# Check if variable is of type int/Integer

Tags: java, integer, int

I am currently using

```
if (element instanceof Integer) 
    return true; 
else 
    return false;
```

but if

```
String element = "5";
```

it will return true. I only want it to return true if elements TRULY is an integer value.

My motivation for this is an exercise at school where I had to make an abstract super-class ObservableList.java with a List elements, and then my sub-class Observable HighscoreList.java has an acceptElement(Object element) method that returns true if elements is the correct dataype for that subclass, and the method is called from an addResult(int element) method. In my case I need integers, and String or chars masked as an integer value is not ok.

Sub-class methods:

```
boolean acceptsElement(Object element) {
    if (element instanceof Integer) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false;
}

public void addResult(int element) {
    int elementsInt;
    if (acceptsElement(element)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {

            try {
                // parsing to int since elements type Object
                elementsInt = (int) elements.get(i);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                elementsInt = 0;
            }

            // adds element to correct position
            if (element < elementsInt || elementsInt == 0) {
                elements.add(i, element);

                // update listeners with new list and position of change
                for (ObservableListListener listListener : listListeners) {
                    listListener.listChanged(this, i);
                }

                // removes elements outside of maxSize
                if (elements.size() >= maxSize) {
                    for (int j = maxSize; j < elements.size(); j++) {
                        elements.remove(j);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("!acceptsElement()");
}
```

super-class methods:

```
public List<Object> elements;
public List<ObservableListListener> listListeners;

abstract boolean acceptsElement(Object element);

    protected void addElement(int index, Object element) {
        if (this.acceptsElement(element)) {
            elements.add(index, element);

            // update listeners with new list and position of change
            for (ObservableListListener listListener : listListeners) {
                listListener.listChanged(this, index);
            }
        } else 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("!acceptsElements()");
    }
```

I am afraid I am very locked down in terms of how to organize everything. I need to pass a jTest program. It tells me that I should have thrown an IllegalArgumentException for "observableList.addElement("5");"

Comment: *if `String element = "5";` it will return true.* False.

Comment: actually on top of what @shmosel has stated it wouldn't compile if the element is a String and you did "if (element instanceof Integer) ".

Comment: Well it does. I have the function "addElement(element)" that I tested with test.addElement("5"). 5 is added to my test-list, because if (element instanceof Integer) is true.

Comment: Maybe you should then show us those pieces of code as well.

Comment: So this is one of those weird cases in which you *have* to use `List list = new ArayList();`, isn't it?  In that case, show us the code you've got so far.

Comment: Yes Makoto it is. It is a really shitty and "academic" execrise where I have to create Interfaces that has a single method, and complicate my inheritance a lot. You can find the code here: https://github.com/vegarab/tdt4100/tree/master/ovinger/src/patterns/observable

ObservableHighScoreList.java implements ObservableList.java. Those are the only relevant classes. jTest jtextest file that gives me the error: https://pastebin.com/WPimNHnv

Comment: Please post *minimal* representative code directly into your question above.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It appears that the problem is that a test doesn't pass, but you didn't post the test, and the code is only partial. Moreover, the test appears to complain about a call to `observableList.addElement("5");`, but there isn't such a method in the posted code. The addElement() method you posted takes two arguments.

Comment: there is, in the super-class observableList. The method addElement() will check if the parameter is an instanceof Integer. If it isnt, then it throws the Exception the test wants. If it IS an instanceof Integer, is simply adds it to the list.

Comment: @VegarAndreasBergum it is not possible for a `String` to evaluate `true` for `instanceof Integer` in Java. So something else is happening, because what you said there cannot be true. Incidentally, you could just use `return (element instanceof Integer)` rather than test a `boolean` in order to find out if it's `boolean` condition is a `boolean`. Also, prefixing a method call with `this.` does nothing. On top of which you're calling a subclass method with that.

Comment: As I said, this is an academic exercise where I need to pass a jTest. I NEED a method called boolean accpetElement(Object element) else Ill fail the test. 
I have provided the methods that are called, but when I create an instance of the superclass observableList and call observableList.addElement("5"), 5 is added to the list called elements, as the integer-value 5, becuase the boolean-check returns true. You can try it out yourself with the code posted in the GitHub link.

Comment: Found the issue in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the

```
else 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("!acceptsElement()");
```

Inside the addElement(Object element)-method. I only had it in the addElement(int index, Object element)-method.

Super-class now looks more like this:

```
public List<Object> elements;
public List<ObservableListListener> listListeners;

    abstract boolean acceptsElement(Object element);

    protected void addElement(int index, Object element) {
        if (acceptsElement(element)) {
            elements.add(index, element);

        // update listeners with new list and position of change
        for (ObservableListListener listListener : listListeners) {
            listListener.listChanged(this, index);
        }
    } else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("!acceptsElement()");
}

protected void addElement(Object element) {
    if (acceptsElement(element)) {
        elements.add(element);

        // update listeners with new list and position of change
        for (ObservableListListener listListener : listListeners) {
            listListener.listChanged(this, elements.indexOf(element));
        }
    } else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("!acceptsElement()");
}
```